# Linux Kernel Mode Vs User Mode

Tags: linux, kernel, process, linux-kernel

I'm trying to better understand the process of switching from user mode to kernel mode on linux systems.

When a process requires access to the low level HW/restricted memory spaces, does it issue a system call to the kernel and the kernel runs the code on its behalf and passes the information back to the process ? or does the kernel put the process in a privileged mode and now the process itself is running in kernel mode and has access to whatever resources it requested ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> does it issue a system call to the kernel and the kernel runs the code
>   on its behalf and passes the information back to the process ? or does
>   the kernel put the process in a privileged mode and now the process
>   itself is running in kernel mode and has access to whatever resources
>   he requested ?

Yes. Any of the above, depending on the system call.

Sometimes a process transitions to kernel mode and does things. Sometimes kernel threads handle the work, especially I/O and file system related. For `gettimeofday()`, vDSO means it just reads the value without going to kernel space.

Read articles introducing the system call interface, such as [LWN's Anatomy of a system call](https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/). Architecture specific, so the details of Linux on x86 are not portable other operating systems or CPU types. But probably have similar concepts.

Use [profiling tools](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) to see what the stacks look like for your workload. Get an idea of the % "system CPU" is typical for your workload.